# Tailwind CSS Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, tailwind-css

No matter what, I cannot get this navbar to properly collapse. I need to change the navbar away from a flex in responsive mode, but it is currently not working.

HTML:

```
 <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-blue-darkest p-6 z-10">
    <div class="flex items-center flex-no-shrink text-white mr-6">
      <svg class="fill-current h-8 w-8 mr-2" width="54" height="54" viewBox="0 0 54 54" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M13.5 22.1c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05zM0 38.3c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05z"
        />
      </svg>
      <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">Tailwind CSS</span>
    </div>
    <div class="block lg:hidden">
      <button class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-white border-white hover:text-blue-darkest hover:bg-white"
        onclick="myFunction()">
        <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <title>Menu</title>
          <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full hidden lg:block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto" id="nav">
      <div class="text-sm lg:flex-grow">
        <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4">
          Docs
        </a>
        <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4">
          Examples
        </a>
        <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white">
          Blog
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-teal hover:bg-white mt-4 lg:mt-0">Download</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nav");
    if (x.className === "hidden") {
        x.classList.toggle("hidden");
    } else {
        console.log("nav");
        x.className = "hidden";
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Answer (score 1):

It's completely possible to use Tailwind CSS's responsive modifiers on display elements as well.

You can change your `nav` element's classes instead of just `flex` to something like `md:flex block` or similar. The correct display value and responsive utility you'll need to tune in on the actual site is by experimenting a bit, of course.

A quote from the Tailwind CSS wiki states:

> To control the display property of an element at a specific breakpoint, add a `{screen}:` prefix to any existing display utility class. For example, use `md:inline-flex` to apply the inline-flex utility at only medium screen sizes and above.

You can read up more [in the Tailwind CSS wiki](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design/).

In addition to this, here's a suggestion: you can shrink your `myFunction` down to just four lines of code. Currently, your if-else statement is just doing what `classList.toggle` already does, but manually. If the check was there because you wanted to check that you got the right element, then be aware that you should **never, ever have multiple elements with the same id on a single page**.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nav");
    x.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```